# copying a set of lines into new file

Tags: text-processing, sed, text-formatting

I have a text file with 100,000 lines or more. I want to copy specific lines from the text file into a new file using:

```
sed -n '1,1000p;1000q' orig-data-file > new-file
```

However, I want to create a series of new file by copying a set of lines in a manner like:

```
First line, last line
1,1000
1001,2000
2001,3000
3001,4000
so on
```

I am not able to write a shell script to automate this process. Can anybody help me. Lot of appreciation in advance.

Comment: Open a terminal and run `man split`

Comment: Thanks, Don. Is there anyway to retain the first line of the large file in each of the newly created file?

Comment: See [Split file including header in each piece](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/276540)

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, you can do this job using `split`.  However, you asked for `sed` so I'll give you `sed`.  (It's a perfectly fine tool for this if you don't want to use `split`.)

Here is an example:

```
$ cat input.txt
Header
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
Line 6
Line 7
Line 8
Line 9
Line 10
Line 11
Line 12
$ sed -n -e '1{w file1' -e 'w file2' -e 'w file3' -e '};2,5w file1' -e '6,10w file2' -e '11,$w file3' input.txt 
$ cat file1
Header
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
$ cat file2
Header
Line 6
Line 7
Line 8
Line 9
Line 10
$ cat file3
Header
Line 11
Line 12
$
```