# Split file by number of lines including header in each one

Tags: files, awk, split

I need to split a `.txt` file into smaller ones containing 100 lines each, including the header. I don't know if this is relevant, but the original file is delimited like this:

```
COLUMN1 | COLUMN2 | COLUMN3
1 | 2 | 3
4 | 5 | 6
7 | 8 | 9
```

I need every file generated from this split to have the header line. Also, they need to be generated in/moved to another directory and follow a name pattern, like `file_01.txt`, `file_02.txt`, etc

Comment: `sed '1d' inputfile.txt | split -l99 outputfile` will generate the files; you can then slap the header line on the resultant files with a simple `for` loop wrapped around `head` and `cat`.

Comment: For a POSIX-only solution, t seems it should be possible with `ex` to copy the header line to the 101st line, 201st line, etc., and then the buffer could be written to `split`, but I don't have time at the moment to explore it.  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `gnu split` you could save the header in a variable then `split` starting from the 2nd line, using the `--filter` option to write the header first and then the 99 lines for each piece and also specify the output directory (e.g. `path to/output dir/`):

```
header=$(head -n 1 infile.txt)
export header
tail -n +2 infile.txt | split -l 99 -d --additional-suffix=.txt \
--filter='{ printf %s\\n "$header"; cat; } >path\ to/output\ dir/$FILE' - file_
```

this will create 100-lines pieces as

```
path to/output dir/file_01.txt
path to/output dir/file_02.txt
path to/output dir/file_03.txt
..............................
```

Comment: Note that `$FILE` is the variable used by `split` for the piece name (see `man split`) so don't change it... :)

Answer (score 6):

```
awk 'NR==1        {a=$0}
    (NR-1)%100==0 {print a > "d/file_" int(1+(NR-1)/100)}
                  {print   > "d/file_" int(1+(NR-1)/100)}'
```

Answer (score 3):

Works for me in bash:

```
lines=100; { read header && sed "1~$((${lines}-1)) s/^/${header}\n/g" | split -l $lines --numeric-suffixes=1 --additional-suffix=.txt - file_ ; } < inputfile.txt
```

Comment: Note: to generate files in another directory first `cd` to it; of course inputfile.txt must then be given as its path, not just filename.