# How to insert a line from file A above the FIRST LINE in file B

Tags: text-processing, text

I have this question constantly, I have searched on the Internet, but to no avail, so I would like to ask for help here.

I have a file with approximately 80,000,000 lines. My job is to split them into files with 500,000 lines each. Well, I use the code:

```
#split -l 500000 myfile segment
```

Question 1:
However, I have a specific task after that. In the original file, the very first line is the `ID`, and I am supposed to copy this line into every split file at the very top (so that every split file has this ID line at the very first line).

I have tried the code:

```
#sed -n 1,1p originalFile >> splitFile
```

It does the job somehow, but it appends the `ID` line at the very BOTTOM of every split file. I hope to have a code such that it puts this `ID` line at the very top (1st line) of every split file.

Question 2 (Incidentally).
I have approx. 170 split files. Is it possible to write a loop to append the ID lines at the very top of every split file?

I would appreciate every piece of advice!

Comment: [Split file by number of lines including header in each one](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/276540) should save you some headache next time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command

```
$ sed -n "1,1p" originalFile >>splitFile
```

will add the ID to the end of `splitFile` since `>>` is telling the shell to *append* the stream to the file. It is also very slow as `sed` will process all 80M lines of `originalFile` before exiting.

After splitting, you'll have about 160 files with names `xaa`, `xab`, `xac` etc. Let's add the header from the original file to these in steps:

```
head -n 1 originalFile >id_line.txt

for f in x??; do
  cat id_line.txt "$f" >tmpfile && mv tmpfile "$f"
done

rm id_line.txt
```

The first command extracts the first line out of `originalFile` into its own file, `id_line.txt`.

The loop iterates over all the generated files, assuming you've used `split` with the default prefix etc., and concatenates the `id_line.txt` and the split files into a temporary file called `tmpfile`.  If that goes well, `tmpfile` replaces the split file.

The last line removes `id_line.txt` which has now served its purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Easy like this.

```
(head -n1 fileA.txt; cat fileB.txt) >result.tmp
```

The file result.tmp will be the FileB with the FileA line above its first line.

When you see the changes is like you want move result.tmp to fileB.txt.

You dont specify in the question what line of fileA you want to insert in fileB, so i am assuming you want the first line.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all the split files have a similar name you can use. No loop needed.

```
LINE_TO_INSERT=$(head -1 originalFile)
sed -i "1s/^/${LINE_TO_INSERT/\\/\\\\}\n/" segment??
```

Comment: Except when you're using GNU `sed`.  Then you need to escape `\ ` in `$LINE_TO_INSERT`, or `sed(1)` will happily take it as a control sequence.

Comment: @SatoKatsura Updated to handle backslashes.

Comment: [`/` and `&` are other characters to escape](/a/129063). But you don't really  need sed here

Comment: Thank you for you help! A follow-up question -- My split files are automatically named as such: segmentaa, segmentab,..., segmentgn. How should I modify your 2nd code to fit the names (so that I could skip the use of loops)?

Comment: @NeverBe I updated the answer to edit files names segment with a two char changing extension.

Answer (score 0):

Try grabbing the contents of `splitFile` with `cat` before overwriting it.

```
echo -e "$(sed -n 1,1p originalFile)\n$(cat splitFile)" > splitFile
```

This is easy to read but may become expensive with massive files.

Answer (score 0):

Try with sed

```
$ sed -i "1i$(sed -n 1p originalFile)" splitFile
```

- `1i` Insert the text that follows at line 1 of the file.
- `$(sed -n 1p originalFile)` get the very first line of the originalFile